# How to store object index in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an abject.

```
let user = { name: 'Rahy', age: 22 }
```

If I take `user. name` I would get 'Rahy', its value. But I want to store user. name in another variable. For example, in `temp`, and when I change the value of `temp` the value of `user. name` should change.

Comment: string is a value type and value type aren't changes with the assignments. You need reference type to get this purpose

Comment: Can't be done, in JS primitive types (strings, numbers, booleans) are stored by value. Objects are stored by refrence however, so you could do `var temp = user; temp.name = "changed"`, and this would change the original `user.name` value

Answer (score 0):

You can reassign `user.name` value when you reassign `temp` value.

```js
let user = { name: 'Rahy', age: 22 };

let { name: temp } = user;

console.log(temp);

temp = user.name = "abc";

console.log(temp, user.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is known as **passing value by reference** in javascript.

The main idea is to point `temp` to the location of `user.name` instead of its value. but in order to achieve this the temp can't be a variable. it has to be property of an object.

for example:

```js
var a = {x:7 , y:7};
var b = a.x;
var c = a;

b = 5;
c.y = 5;

console.log(a.x, a.y);
```

In this example value of y changes but value of x remains same. So you'd have to make temp a property of an object.